# how to use a for each loop with supabase in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, supabase

I have this code:

```
const fetchSongs = async() => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('songs')
  .select()
```

is it possible to assign the data to a global variable?

I tried assigning the variable inside the function but it didnt work

```
  const fetchSongs = async() => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('songs')
  .select()
  const songs = data
  
  }
```